# Связь нескольких моделей Django

Tags: python, django, view, jinja2

Есть три связанные модели. Мастерская, мастер и занятость(WorksOn), какой мастер в какой мастерской работает. В каждой мастерской могут работать несколько мастеров(поэтому ForeignKey к Workshop), но каждый мастер может работать только в одной мастерской(поэтому OneToOne Field к Master)

models.py

```
class Workshop(models.Model):
    """Мастерская"""
    title = models.CharField('Название', unique = True, max_length = 50)
    description = models.TextField('Описание')
    time_table = models.CharField('Расписание', max_length = 25, default = 'без выходных')
    addres = models.CharField('Адрес', unique = True,  max_length = 100, default = '')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Мастерская'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Мастерские'


class Master(models.Model):
    """Мастер"""
    name = models.CharField('Имя', max_length = 50)
    experience = models.PositiveIntegerField('Стаж(лет)', default = 0, help_text = 'укажите стаж мастера')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Мастер'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Мастера'


class WorksOn(models.Model):
    """Занятость мастеров в мастерских(мастер работает только в одной мастерской,
    в мастерской может быть несколько мастеров)
    """
    workshop = models.ForeignKey(Workshop, verbose_name = 'Мастерская', 
on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='work')
    master = models.OneToOneField(Master, verbose_name = 'Мастер', 
on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='worker')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Занятость'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Занятости'
```

views.py

```
def masters(request):
    masters_info = Master.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'workshop/masters.html')


def tools(request):
    tools_info = Tool.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'workshop/tools.html', {'title' : 'Наше оборудование', 'tools_info': tools_info})


def workshops(request):
    workshop_info = Workshop.objects.all()
    works_on_info = WorksOn.objects.all()
    masters_info = Master.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'workshop/workshops.html', {'title': 'Наши мастерские', 'workshop_info': workshop_info, 'works_on_info': works_on_info, 'masters_info': masters_info})
```

Шаблон workshops.html

```
{% extends 'workshop/base.html' %}

{% block title %}
{{ title }}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Наши мастерские</h1>
    {% for el in workshop_info %}
        <div class="alert alert-success mt-2">
            <h3>{{ el.title }}</h3>
            <p><b>Описание:</b></p>
            <p>{{ el.description }}</p>
            <p><b>Режим работы:</b></p>
            <p>{{ el.time_table }}</p>
            <p><b>Адрес:</b></p>
            <p>{{ el.addres }}</p>
            <p><b>Мастера, работающие в этой мастерской:</b></p>
            {% for elem in workshop_info.worker.all %}
                <p>{{ elem.master }}</p>
            {% endfor %}

        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Пытаюсь на странице вывести вместе с информацией о мастерских(название, адрес, описание) мастеров, которые в них работают через WorksOn и соответствующий related_name, однако не выводится ничего, по сему и прошу помощи, как реализовать вывод к каждой мастерской работающих в ней мастеров? Непосредственно в примере пробую хотя бы просто всех мастеров, которые где-то работают вывести. Пробовал через filter(), но тоже не получилось, без related_name тоже, переделывать модели мне кажется неправильным, не хранить же списком у мастерской мастеров без WorksOn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Под рукой компа нет , но вроде как-то так :

```
{% for elem in works_on_info %}
{% if elem.workshop ==  el %}
            <p>{{ elem.master.name }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
```

Это второй цикл , не могу точно сказать правильно ли , негде проверить